# Signup validation form error Android

Tags: java, android, regex, validation, parse-platform

I'm writing some code to sign up for a parse account. I'm using various validation regexs' for my Username, Email and Password. But everytime I run this, it fails bringing up errors I've put.

Here's the code,

```
   private boolean isFormInputValid(String username, String password, String c_password, String email, String name) {
    mUsernameEtxt.setError(null);
    mPasswordEtxt.setError(null);
    mCPasswordEtxt.setError(null);
    mEmailEtxt.setError(null);
    mNameEtxt.setError(null);

    // validate the username
    if (username == null || username.isEmpty()) {
        mUsernameEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_username));
        mUsernameEtxt.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }


    // validate the password
    if (password == null || password.isEmpty()) {
        mPasswordEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_password));
        mPasswordEtxt.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }


    // validate the confirm password
    if ((!c_password.equals(password))) {
        mCPasswordEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_c_password));
        mCPasswordEtxt.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }


    // validate the email
    if (email == null || email.isEmpty()) {
        mEmailEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_email));
        mEmailEtxt.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    // validate the name
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        mNameEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_name));
        mNameEtxt.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean isValidUsername(final String username) {

    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;

    final String USERNAME_PATTERN = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{4,}$";

    pattern = Pattern.compile(USERNAME_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(username);

    return matcher.matches();

}

public boolean isValidPassword(final String password) {

    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;

    final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=\\S+$).{8,}$";

    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    return matcher.matches();

}

public boolean isValidEmail(final String email) {

    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;

    final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$";

    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

    return matcher.matches();

}

// OnClickListener Implementations
private class SignUpOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the username and password from the view
        String username = mUsernameEtxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
        String password = mPasswordEtxt.getText().toString().trim();
        String c_password = mCPasswordEtxt.getText().toString();
        String email = mEmailEtxt.getText().toString().trim();
        String name = mNameEtxt.getText().toString().trim();
        if (isFormInputValid(username, password, c_password, email, name)) {
            if (isValidUsername(mUsernameEtxt.getText().toString().trim())) {
                if (isValidPassword(mPasswordEtxt.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    if (isValidEmail(mEmailEtxt.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                        user.setUsername(username);
                        user.setPassword(password);
                        user.setEmail(email);
                        user.put("name", name);
                        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    // Successful sign up, take user to the MainActivity
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    // Sign up didn't succeed, most likely the username/email is taken
                                    TextView error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
                                    error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    error.setText(getString(R.string.error_username_email_taken));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        mEmailEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_email_notvalid));
                        TextView error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
                        error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        error.setText(getString(R.string.error_email_notvalid_detail));

                        Log.d("error", "email invalid");
                    }
                }else {
                    mPasswordEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_password_weak));
                    TextView error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
                    error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    error.setText(getString(R.string.error_password_weak_detail));

                    Log.d("error", "password invalid");
                }
            } else {
                mUsernameEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_username_notvalid));
                TextView error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
                error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                error.setText(getString(R.string.error_username_notvalid_detail));

                Log.d("error", "username invalid");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the error you got for each password.

Comment: @vks the code doesn't work.

Comment: So at which line error occurs,what is the error ,when does it come ?

Comment: @vks Ive changed the code, errors dont seem to come up, but now it refuses to sign up, FYI: I updated the code.

Comment: It doesnt sign up!!! what data you give?what error you get like `password invalid` or nething else:

Comment: It says that my Username or Email is already taken.
R.string.error_username_email_taken @vks

Comment: `^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$` your email pattern should probably be this.....

Comment: @vks I'm already using it. You can see it in the code I've given.

Comment: make it "\\" instead of "\\\\"